# How to Continue The Text from one textblock to another textblock if the first textblock text length is limited?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress-wpf

I am creating a bank cheques so in that i have 6 textblocks first 2 is for date and name on the cheque 3rd,4th,5th is for amount in words and 6th is for amount in figures so endusers of my organization will provide date,name and amount in figures and amount in figures will be relected and converted in amount in words upto here it is fine but my requirement is in the 3rd overflowing and i would like to continue the text in 4th textblock.

```
public ICICICHEQUE()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (!this.IsVisible)
        {
            this.Show();
        }
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        this.Activate();
        this.Topmost = true;
        this.Focus();
        this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        if (txtblckAmountInFigures.Text != null)
        {
            ConvertTxtBlockInDecimal();

        }


    }

    private void ConvertTxtBlockInDecimal()
    {
        txtblckAmountInWords.Text = UtilityMethods.ConvertToWords(Convert.ToDecimal(txtblckAmountInFigures.Text), "isCheque") + "only/-"+"\r\n";

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to split your code and use these two methods

```
public static string DecimalToText(string decimalPart)
{
   string[] digits = {"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"};
   string result = "";
   foreach(char c in decimalPart)
   {
       int i = (int)c - 48;
       if (i < 0 || i > 9) return ""; // invalid number, don't return anything
       result += " " + digits[i];
   }
   return result;
}

public static string NumberToText(int number, bool useAnd, bool useArab)
{
    if (number == 0) return "Zero";

    string and = useAnd ? "and " : ""; // deals with using 'and' separator

    if (number == -2147483648) return "Minus Two Hundred " + and + "Fourteen Crore Seventy Four Lakh Eighty Three Thousand Six Hundred " + and +"Forty Eight";

    int[] num = new int[4];
    int first = 0;
    int u, h, t;
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    if (number < 0)
    {
        sb.Append("Minus ");
        number = -number;
    }
    string[] words0 = {"" ,"One ", "Two ", "Three ", "Four ", "Five " ,"Six ", "Seven ", "Eight ", "Nine "};
    string[] words1 = {"Ten ", "Eleven ", "Twelve ", "Thirteen ", "Fourteen ", "Fifteen ", "Sixteen ", "Seventeen ", "Eighteen ", "Nineteen "};
    string[] words2 = {"Twenty ", "Thirty ", "Forty ", "Fifty ", "Sixty ", "Seventy ","Eighty ", "Ninety "};
    string[] words3 = { "Thousand ", "Lakh ", "Crore " };
    num[0] = number % 1000; // units
    num[1] = number / 1000;
    num[2] = number / 100000;
    num[1] = num[1] - 100 * num[2]; // thousands
    num[3] = number / 10000000; // crores
    num[2] = num[2] - 100 * num[3]; // lakhs
    for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (num[i] != 0)
        {
            first = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = first; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (num[i] == 0) continue;

        u = num[i] % 10; // ones 
        t = num[i] / 10;
        h = num[i] / 100; // hundreds
        t = t - 10 * h; // tens

        if (h > 0) sb.Append(words0[h] + "Hundred ");
        if (u > 0 || t > 0)
        {
            if (h > 0 || i < first) sb.Append(and);

            if (t == 0)
                sb.Append(words0[u]);
            else if (t == 1)
                sb.Append(words1[u]);
            else
                sb.Append(words2[t - 2] + words0[u]);
        }
        if (i != 0) sb.Append(words3[i - 1]);
    }

    string temp = sb.ToString().TrimEnd();

    if (useArab && Math.Abs(number) >= 1000000000)
    {
        int index = temp.IndexOf("Hundred Crore");
        if (index > -1) return temp.Substring(0, index) + "Arab" + temp.Substring(index + 13);
        index = temp.IndexOf("Hundred");
        return temp.Substring(0, index) + "Arab" + temp.Substring(index + 7);
    } 
    return temp;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use substring to split the text and display in 2 textboxes.

```
var requiredText = UtilityMethods.ConvertToWords(Convert.ToDecimal(txtblckAmountInFigures.Text), "isCheque") + "only/-"+"\r\n";

if(requiredText.Count > 255)
{
    textbox1.Text = requiredText.subString(0,255);
    textbox2.Text = requiredText.subString(255,requiredText.Count-1);
}
else
{
    textbox1.Text = requiredText;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much i have 3 textbox and i would like to continue the text in 3rd textbox when i tried to do it is not working?

Comment: What changes?? Without seeing your code, I cant comment on it. Mainly this is the logic used for splitting the text. Using this logic and proper debugging, you could easily split the string.

Comment: Is there any way to find the actual text length of a textblock?because text is trimming.

Comment: Are you talking about the MaxLength property? `textBox1.MaxLength = 25;`. This will accept only 25 characters in that textbox.

Comment: it is for textbox but here i am using textblock

Comment: Make the textbox readonly then. Because textblock doesn’t have this property.  If you’re particular about using textblock itself, then you have to limit the characters by code. Ie You should split the entire text according to the width of textbox in your UI.